# Exclude items from search result based on attribute value

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have an attribute as *Discontinue* in admin for the product which is of drop down type having values yes or no.

I do not want to display the product in search result if the product is marked as discontinued.I want to apply a filter based on the value of Discontinue attribute

How can I do this? 
In catalog search module in which file should I make changes?
Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the visibility of such products to "Catalog" instead of "Catalog, Search".

You can do it in the following way :

```
$_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach($_product as $product)
{
   if($product->getDiscontinued()==1)
   {
     $product->setVisibility(2); // try either 2 or 3 dont remember if 2 is for catalog or for search
    $product->setSave();

  }

}
```

you can run this as cron ... I have not tested the code ...you will have to run it I just have typed it here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion , but I want to do using filter while loading search result product collection.